# Perl: Move to next item in loop before it is done executing

Tags: perl, loops, foreach

I have a perl script that is like so:

```
foreach my $addr ('http://site1.com', ...., 'http://site2.com') {
    my $script = `curl -m 15 $addr`;
    *do stuff with $script*
}
```

The `-m` sets a timeout of 15 seconds. Is there a way to make it if a user pushes a key, it stops the current execution and moves onto the next item in the foreach? I know `last;` can move to the next item but I am unsure of how to link this to the key being pushed and how to do it while the curl script is running

Edit: So based on the answers it seems difficult to do it while curl is running. Would it be possible to push a key while curl is running and have it skip to the next item in the loop *as soon as* the curl script returns (or times out after 15sec)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you've got with this, is that when you run `curl` perl hands over control and waits for completion. It blocks until it's 'done'.

So it's not as easy to do this as it might seem.

As another poster alludes to - you can use a variety of parallel processing options. I would suggest the easiest is to move away from using 'any' key, and require a ctrl-c.

So you'd then do:

```
foreach my $addr ('http://site1.com', ...., 'http://site2.com') {
     my $pid = open ( my $curl_fh, "-|", "curl -m 15 $addr" );
     $SIG{'INT'} = sub { print "Aborting fetch of $addr"; kill $pid };
     while ( <$curl_fh> ) {
         print;
     }
     #might want to set it to something else. 
     #undef means 'ctrl-c' will abort the whole program. 
     #IGNORE means exactly what it says on the tin.
     #important to change it though, as it has a specific pid it'll kill, 
     #and that might cause problems. 
     $SIG{'INT'} = undef;
}
```

What this does is configure `SIGINT` (e.g. ctrl-c) so it doesn't kill your program, but does kill the sub-process.

If you wanted to look at other options, I'd offer:

- Multithreading, spawn a thread to 'do' the curl fetching in the background and use `Thread::Queue` to pass results back and forth. (`Thread::Queue` supports nonblocking checks).
- Forking - fork a sub process to do the curl, and use your 'main' process to send a signal if a key is pressed.
- `IO::Select` such that you're not making blocking reads on your process.

Comment: I have updated the original question. So essentially, if I can see the script is going to timeout, I want to move it to the next item before 15 seconds is up.

Comment: Why do you have a 15s timeout in that case? Why not make it shorter?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have two options:

**1. Use threads**

Create a new thread, call desired system function there. Wait for output. In another thread, check for user input. On input, you can kill the child process. When child process has finished, you can ignore user input.

Such a solution seems to be rather complex, with a lot of synchronization needed, probably with using signals. Risky.

**2. Use non-blocking IO**

Please read [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=55241) thread. It explains how to make non-blocking IO reads from either a file or a pipe. You'd like to make a non-blocking read from pipe (created with `open`), then non-blocking read from `STDIN`, loop.

Seems like a way to go, but, alas, rather complex as well.

Comment: You don't need signals for threading. You might if you're doing it with `fork()`. 
You can also probably trap-and-kill 'interrupt' signals like `ctrl-c` rather than `any key`.

Comment: I have updated the original question. So essentially, if I can see the script is going to timeout, I want to move it to the next item before 15 seconds is up.